# Client side image resize and save

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

is there a way to resize and save an image to a temp file through a web browser client side?

What I am trying to accomplish is resize an image to a max 1024px wide/high, save it locally and then upload the resized image to a server.

The reason is that I am building an online app that allows users to upload a maximum of 6 high res images upto 4mb each. Then when on the server I resize to 1024px wide/high which is actually only 200kb or so. This is a bit of a waste uploading 4mb only to be resized to a smaller file size so I am hoping there is a way to resize, save a temp file client side before uploading.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: as far as i know, you can't. better use the server instead.

Comment: You can, but it requires much more than server side. You would have to use something alone the lines of JQuery (Ajax), flash, or such. You're better off doing it server side. It's a simple line of code, but I see where you are getting at.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is the clients test keep failing because the images are too big and his internet connection is quite slow. I am using Blueimp image uploader with sequential uploads but I have multiple instances of the uploader on a single page and the sequential feature only works within each instance, not across multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5, I think... Go around here [HTML5 canvas(crop image)](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/)

Answer (score 0):

The first you need is to get the upload image before it uploads - Thats possible with HTML5 files property of an input[type=file] element.

If thats done you would need to modify the image data for rezising with JS/HTML5 - don't know how that works.

Than you can upload the modified image using XHR.